# LEX: Refreshing standard page after Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, lightning

In LEX, you cannot add an attachment to a Task.  So I wrote a simple VF page and controller which allows us, and added it as a custom button to the LEX buttons.  It is working fine, but when I return to the page to view the Task, I need to refresh the page before the newly added attachment is seen.  Is there a way of forcing the page to be refreshed from within the VF/Apex code?  Here's the relevant Apex code:

```
public PageReference upload() {

   // Code to insert attachment, works correctly

   // Now return to view Task
     PageReference retPage = new ApexPages.StandardController(taskx).view();
    retPage.setRedirect(true);
    return retPage;
  }
```

Comment: Unless things have changed, the user sessionId for a visualforce page is different than the user sessionId in LEX since they're each sent from different servers. Hopefully that will help point you to a solution.